# Handling viewset that has a serializer with multiple foreignkeys

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have this serializer:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'user', 'movie', 'timestamp', 'review_text',)
```

I want to mention that `user` and `movie` are both `ForeignKey`s defined in `models.py` for `Review` model. Here is the model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    review_text = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{movie} review by {user}'.format(user=self.user, movie=self.movie)
```

I want to create a viewset, but if I do something like this:

```
class ReviewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer
```

and register it like this:

```
router.register(r'reviews', views.ReviewsViewSet, 'reviews')
```

won't work, it requires me to provide a `movie field` as logged here:

```
AttributeError at /api/reviews/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `movie` on serializer `ReviewSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Movie` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'movie'.
```

Thanks in advance.

*Edited.*

Comment: user is foreign key, as well as the user ?  It is not clear what you mean. Also include desired functionality - example of an endpoint, input and output.

Comment: @yierstem it's not clear what you're asking. Please make it clear

Comment: Sorry for late edit and thank you for bringing me this to attention. I edited the post.

Comment: your queryset = Movie.objects.all() should be Review.objects.all() as you want to serialize Review (from the serializer code) not the movie. Indeed - Movie has no movie attribute, this is why your view fails.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. But now I get `IntegrityError at /api/reviews/
NOT NULL constraint failed: api_review.user_id`, I don't actually know why this occurs.